# How can I make this kind of grid in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

[image: Super Connect 4]

How can I make this or similar type of grid in android. Any link or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That what I know. But what I mean is how can I make this grid with that type of hole in it. Is this some kind of component in android that I need to include in TableLayout?

Answer (score 2):

You can go for TableLayout, Go through the code below, you will get the idea.

Use ImageButton and 3 types of images set to it.
- With the hole
- Withe yellow ball
- With blue ball

```
TableLayout GridTable=new TableLayout(this);        
ImageButton[][] gridButton=new ImageButton[3][3];
GridTable.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    TableRow[] gridRow=new TableRow[3];        
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gridRow[i]=new TableRow(this);
        gridRow[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));           
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {               
            gridButton[i][j]=new ImageButton(this);
            gridButton[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.<your_image>);   
            gridRow[i].addView(gridButton[i][j]);
        }   
        GridTable.addView(gridRow[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Are seatTable,seatButton,seatRow should be GridTable, gridbutton, gridRow correspondingly?

Comment: yes, of course. its a little mistake. when i copied it from my code. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using data to populate the grid, it might be easier to use a GridView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

So each cell is backed by data, might be simpler to hack with.